# Is it better to define a custom distance metric in sklearn k-NN or use a GPU k-NN package with high-dimensional vectors?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I'm currently using sklearn's k-NN with a custom distance metric and the ball tree algorithm to find about 20 nearest neighbors for a dataset that contains a few million points.  The custom distance metric attempts to find distance between vectors that contain both categorical variables (encoded as integers) and continuous values.  Of course, it's really dang slow, and I've looked into other options.  The GPU stuff out there looks promising, but I'd have to convert my categorical variables to one-hots, making the vectors pretty enormous (on the order of 10k dimensions).  I'm wondering what the tradeoff looks like here - is it better to continue using the k-NN and praying it eventually finishes, or should I bite the bullet and do the one-hots with the GPU methods? Is there a clever way around this?

Comment: I would attempt to use the GPU methods, knn is really slow. Please update your question if you find a solution, this is pretty interesting.

Comment: What gpu stuff are you interested in? Even after one-hot, you'll still need to apply some distance metric like euclidean on encoded vectors. Can you not do this with CPU? Passing data to/from GPU takes time- are you sure CPU wouldn't be better?

Comment: I'm worried that applying a distance metric with a CPU on one-hot encoded vectors will be really slow; if the vectors have ~10k dimensions, I'm probably going to get enough speedup from using a GPU that the data passing will be worth it.